# Selecting row with latest timestamp MySQL with Duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I am trying to select a row with the latest timestamp. Here's a sample of the table:

```
+--------+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+---------+-----------+---------------+----------------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| id     | tester_name | frame            | board_name | config | part_no | serial_no | license_count | legal_enabling | last_checked        | log_name                                |
+--------+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+---------+-----------+---------------+----------------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------+ 
| 162936 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 6      | 974-331-44 | 302501d   |               |                | 2015-08-01 19:48:48 | IGXLEventLog.8.1.2015.19.48.15.054.log  |
| 162937 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 7      | 974-331-44 | c0165ec   |               |                | 2015-08-01 19:48:48 | IGXLEventLog.8.1.2015.19.48.15.054.log  |
| 162938 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 8      | 974-331-44 | c13100e   |               |                | 2015-08-01 19:48:48 | IGXLEventLog.8.1.2015.19.48.15.054.log  |
| 162939 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 9      | 974-331-44 | 302c919   |               |                | 2015-08-01 19:48:48 | IGXLEventLog.8.1.2015.19.48.15.054.log  |
| 162941 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 14     | 974-331-44 | c00b41b   |               |                | 2015-08-01 19:48:48 | IGXLEventLog.8.1.2015.19.48.15.054.log  |
| 162942 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 15     | 974-331-44 | c13101e   |               |                | 2015-08-01 19:48:48 | IGXLEventLog.8.1.2015.19.48.15.054.log  |
| 162943 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 16     | 974-331-44 | 3014a1b   |               |                | 2015-08-01 19:48:48 | IGXLEventLog.8.1.2015.19.48.15.054.log  |
| 162944 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 17     | 974-331-44 | 302cc7e   |               |                | 2015-08-01 19:48:48 | IGXLEventLog.8.1.2015.19.48.15.054.log  |
| 166555 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 6      | 974-331-44 | 302501d   |               |                | 2015-07-29 02:32:39 | IGXLEventLog.7.29.2015.02.32.05.475.log |
| 166556 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 7      | 974-331-44 | c0165ec   |               |                | 2015-07-29 02:32:39 | IGXLEventLog.7.29.2015.02.32.05.475.log |
| 166557 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 8      | 974-331-44 | c13100e   |               |                | 2015-07-29 02:32:39 | IGXLEventLog.7.29.2015.02.32.05.475.log |
| 166558 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 9      | 974-331-44 | 302c919   |               |                | 2015-07-29 02:32:39 | IGXLEventLog.7.29.2015.02.32.05.475.log |
| 166560 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 14     | 974-331-44 | c00b41b   |               |                | 2015-07-29 02:32:39 | IGXLEventLog.7.29.2015.02.32.05.475.log |
| 166561 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 15     | 974-331-44 | c13101e   |               |                | 2015-07-29 02:32:39 | IGXLEventLog.7.29.2015.02.32.05.475.log |
| 166562 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 16     | 974-331-44 | 3014a1b   |               |                | 2015-07-29 02:32:39 | IGXLEventLog.7.29.2015.02.32.05.475.log |
| 166563 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 17     | 974-331-44 | 302cc7e   |               |                | 2015-07-29 02:32:39 | IGXLEventLog.7.29.2015.02.32.05.475.log | 
+--------+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+---------+-----------+---------------+----------------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

The query I use to get the above is

```
SELECT ti.* 
FROM New_OTPMS.TBL_TESTER_ONLINE_INFO ti 
INNER JOIN TBL_TESTER_LIST tl 
ON ti.tester_name = tl.tester_name 
WHERE ti.board_name = 'HSD-M' 
AND tl.tester_type = 'UFLEX' 
AND ti.tester_name = 'UFLEX-10' 
ORDER BY ti.tester_name;
```

As you can see it just gets everything from the table. I want to get the rows that are based on the latest time stamp only. NOTE: Not one row with the latest time stamp, but the non duplicated row based on `config`, with the SAME latest time stamps.

The latest/the rows that I want are

```
+--------+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+---------+-----------+---------------+----------------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| id     | tester_name | frame            | board_name | config | part_no | serial_no | license_count | legal_enabling | last_checked        | log_name                                |
+--------+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+---------+-----------+---------------+----------------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| 166555 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 6      | 974-331-44 | 302501d   |               |                | 2015-07-29 02:32:39 | IGXLEventLog.7.29.2015.02.32.05.475.log |
| 166556 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 7      | 974-331-44 | c0165ec   |               |                | 2015-07-29 02:32:39 | IGXLEventLog.7.29.2015.02.32.05.475.log |
| 166557 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 8      | 974-331-44 | c13100e   |               |                | 2015-07-29 02:32:39 | IGXLEventLog.7.29.2015.02.32.05.475.log |
| 166558 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 9      | 974-331-44 | 302c919   |               |                | 2015-07-29 02:32:39 | IGXLEventLog.7.29.2015.02.32.05.475.log |
| 166560 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 14     | 974-331-44 | c00b41b   |               |                | 2015-07-29 02:32:39 | IGXLEventLog.7.29.2015.02.32.05.475.log |
| 166561 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 15     | 974-331-44 | c13101e   |               |                | 2015-07-29 02:32:39 | IGXLEventLog.7.29.2015.02.32.05.475.log |
| 166562 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 16     | 974-331-44 | 3014a1b   |               |                | 2015-07-29 02:32:39 | IGXLEventLog.7.29.2015.02.32.05.475.log |
| 166563 | UFLEX-10    | TEST_HEAD TH 1 | HSD-M      | 17     | 974-331-44 | 302cc7e   |               |                | 2015-07-29 02:32:39 | IGXLEventLog.7.29.2015.02.32.05.475.log |
+--------+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+---------+-----------+---------------+----------------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Any help on this?

EDIT: I have edited the data above so that it corresponds to the question.

Comment: This is the most frequently asked question under the mysql tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT ti.*
FROM New_OTPMS.TBL_TESTER_ONLINE_INFO ti
INNER JOIN TBL_TESTER_LIST tl
ON ti.tester_name = tl.tester_name
WHERE ti.board_name = 'DC30'
AND tl.tester_type = 'UFLEX'
AND ti.tester_name = 'UFLEX-10'
AND ti.last_checked = (
    SELECT MAX(last_checked) 
    FROM New_OTPMS.TBL_TESTER_ONLINE_INFO
    WHERE
        board_name = 'DC30'
        AND tester_name = 'UFLEX-10'    
)
```

Comment: This works, but what if I have different `config` numbers but with the same `last_checked` or aka latest time? I want to get all of them. Example, there'll be `1`, `16`, `17`, but all with the same latest timestamp. How do I get all?

Comment: I tried your new answer, it will give me back the old results instead of the rows with latest time stamp.

Comment: Returns nothing this time

Comment: update your question near "The latest/the rows that I want are", there should be NOT 2015-07-29 02:32:39, but 2015-08-01 19:48:48 ?

Comment: Great, just what I was looking for. One last question, what if I had to do the query for many different `tester_name`? Do I use the select like the one in your answer? Or should I do a separate query (I'm using PHP) and just use this query to iterate through each `tester_name`?

Comment: i think u can do it in one query, but it will be more complex. iterate is not a good way... but a way. sorry for english

Comment: No worries I understand your statement. I've tried the iterating and yeah it is not a good way, slowing down my web application by like more than 1 minute.  I will try to find out how can I do it with the query. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ti.*
FROM New_OTPMS.TBL_TESTER_ONLINE_INFO ti
INNER JOIN TBL_TESTER_LIST tl
ON ti.tester_name = tl.tester_name
WHERE ti.board_name = 'DC30'
AND tl.tester_type = 'UFLEX'
AND ti.tester_name = 'UFLEX-10'
ORDER BY ti.last_checked DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Above sql should work. Your original sql is ordering by name and not the time. You can add LIMIT 1 at the end if u just want that one latest row.

Comment: This still gives me the old row

Comment: try changing DESC to ASC and remove the GROUP BY

Comment: may I know which row is returned ?

Comment: The one that I didn't want, whereby the ID is 98965. And I see you've changed your answer. This will take the latest one indeed but however, what if I have a few different `config` numbers with a same timestamp(latest) instead of all `1`? I want to get all the different `config`. How would the query be then?

Comment: try adding "GROUP BY ti.config" and remove LIMIT 1

Comment: Tried as you suggested, it does return individual `config` but the timestamp is not the latest when I do that.